# Launcher Activity theme visible on closing another activity

Tags: android, android-theme

I have a Splash Screen Activity (as a launcher) with a theme. The theme has a red background and an image.

On opening the app, SplashScreenActivity shows its theme followed by rendering the XML UI (and performs some API calls) and then opens Home Page. Also while opening Home Page it finishes the SplashScreenActivity.

Now if I close an ActivityX and redirect to ActivityY then the theme that was set on SplashScreenActivity shows up. Why is this so? This theme was set on SplashScreenActivity & not on ActivityX or ActivityY.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

Do apply theme in every activity, just reuse the theme if you want as:

```
android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
```